# My android froze and was replaced. unable to access my pokemon account

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Because my phone froze I was unable to log out of pokemon. My phone was replaced
and now I only have the option to start a new account. My understanding from what I read I had to be logged out of pokemon in order to transfer to new phone

Answer (score 0):

Just enter with the account you entered with, for example, if you signed up with your google account, sign in with your google account, and also enter your birthday.